# CookieAuthentication - How do I redirect to Login page when ExpireTimeSpan is over?

Tags: ajax, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies

I am creating an asp.net mvc5 application that uses Cookie Authentication.
My startup.cs code is as follows.

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "myApplicationCookie",
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOut")

        });
    }
}
```

After ExpireTimeSpan is passed ie. after 10 minutes, if I reload the page, then application is redirected to login page. But if i make ajax request, then nothing happens and it is not redirected to login page either. How do I redirect to login page on ajax request after ExpireTimeSpan is over? Please help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your Session timeout in **web.config** file.
paste the code in web.config file in your project

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In **global.asax** file create an event like

```
   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){  
       // Code that runs when a new session is started  
       if (Session["user"] != null)  
       {  
          // Navigate to welcome page
       }  
       else  
       {  
          // Navigate to login page
       } 
   }
```

When the session is timedout it will be automatically redirected to login page.

**Note :** The timeout is in mins.

Comment: Will this work with the startup class i got above? I have used claimsIdentity to store logged in user information. Not session. Will this workout for my scenario?

Comment: This approach is based on session only